# DateTime syntax reference

Tags: asp.net, razor

I understand there are [no complete reference docs available for Razor as yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773411/asp-net-razor-reference-documentation), but would like to know what the various date format options are. Such as:

```
DateTime.Now.Day
DateTime.Now.Month
DateTime.Now.Year
DateTime.Now.Date
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
```

etc etc

Is there a complete reference anywhere for DateTime?
How do I get just DD/MM/YYYY without 00:00:00 being appended for example?

Comment: Note that this would not be Razor-specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DateTime class is part of the .NET framework. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) documentation.

To format dates, you can use the `.ToString(string format)` method:

```
@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is actually a .NET type. The full documentation is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

For your particular question you would want to use the [`ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) method:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: `ToShortDateString()` is culture-sensitive, so if the page was being served from my PC, the dates would be formatted as dd.M.yyyy

Comment: That's great to know - thanks for the link to the documentation.